# What is an example for a strictly increasing strictly concave differentiable function with no lower or upper bound on $\Bbb R$?

Tags: functions

I am looking for an example of a function on $\Bbb R$ that is

- strictly increasing,
- strictly concave,
- differentiable and
- has no lower or upper bound.

Comment: $f(x)=2x-\sqrt{x^2+1},$ for instance.

Comment: "*symmetric to the origin*" stands for *even* or for *odd*? Anyway, the solutions set is empty if you add such a constraint.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I thought it stands for f(x) = -f(x).

Comment: That means $f(x)=0$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I meant actually axis symmetry to the -x axis.

Comment: Symmetric with respect to the $x$-axis? So $f(x)$ is at the same time $a$ and $-a$ ?!

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio the $-x$ axis I meant. At least that I can paint on a paper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try $$f(x)=x-e^{-x} $$

Comment: Thanks. That seems to work.

Comment: Actually, now that I see it. Is it possible to have it also symmetric to the origin?

Comment: @Daniel: no odd or even function may fulfill the given constraints.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Wow. Interesting that this is actually impossible.

Comment: @Daniel: if you try to draw a graph, that is pretty trivial, actually.

Comment: Oh, I mixed it up

Comment: Symmetrici to the origin means $f(-x)=-f(x)$, hence $f''(-x)=-f''(x)$, so you cannot have *strictly* concave

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio What I meant was a symmetry at the axis given by -x. Not sure why I thought this has to do with point symmetry.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thanks. I got confused. Have updated it in the comment.